# Java longest subsequence

Tags: java

I have an array, i'd like to calculate the length of the longest subsequence made by equals numbers:
Example: 5 1 1 9 9 9 4 4 6 6 4 4 4   --> the length of the longest subsequence is 3 (9 9 9).
This is what i got so far but it doesn't work.

```
int lung=0, lungmax=0;
        int indice = 0;
        int [] values = new int [30];  
        for(int k=0; k<30; k++)
        {
            if (values[k]==values[k+1])
            {
                lung++;
                if (lung>lungmax)
                {
                    lungmax=lung;
                    indice=values[k];
                }
            }   
            else lung=0;
        }

        lungmax = lungmax++;
    System.out.println("the length of the longest subsequence is: "+lungmax);
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? What does it give you, what do you expect it to give you.

Comment: I assume you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on this line `if (values[k]==values[k+1])`, right? Maybe you should loop while* `k < values.length - 1` so `k+1` won't exceed the array bounds. (* this is *not* a recommendation to use a `while` loop instead)

Comment: why not the answer is 3(4 4 4 ) in ur example?

Comment: @SUDHIR  I want the first longest subsequent.

Comment: @Tom    yes, i knew it but if I write System.out.println(values[k]) before if (values[k]==values[k+1]) I get 1 1 9 9 9 4 4 6 6 4 4 4 and it doesn't print the first element (5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. By applying my approach, the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException has been eliminated.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int lung = 1, lungmax = 0;
    int indice = 0;
    int[] values = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6};
    for (int k = 1; k < values.length; k++) {

        if (values[k - 1] == values[k]) {
            lung++;
            if (lung > lungmax) {
                lungmax = lung;
                indice = values[k];
            }
        } else {
            lung = 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("the length of the longest subsequence is: " + indice + "/" + lungmax);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code has two errors:

```
for(int k=0; k<30; k++) {
    if (values[k]==values[k+1]) {
```

This loop will be executed until `k` reaches value `30`. Therefore, the last used value for `k` is `29`. If you use that value in the `if` statement, you'll exceed that array bounds by calling `values[k+1]` (== `values[30]`).

Change that loop to:

```
for(int k = 0; k < values.length - 1; k++) {
```

The second problem is this line:

```
lungmax = lungmax++;
```

This is the same as:

```
int temp = lungmax;
lungmax = lungmax + 1;
lungmax = temp;
```

As you can see, you're "ignoring" the increment. Change that line to:

```
lungmax++;
```

Comment: Plus : I think lung++ will not work at 3rd 9 because 9==6 is false. and hence lungmax for 9 remains 2. and it will take 4's indice

Answer (score 1):

Or simply 
make following changes

```
int lungmax=1;
```

and replace

```
lungmax=lung
```

with

```
lungmax++;
```

and remove last `lungmax=lungmax++`

plus what Tom suggested : `k<30-1`